# How to handle Web service and back-end/infrastructure source code versioning

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, visual-studio, versioning

I have a "**class Library**" in my solution that is being used by my "**WebService**". This web serice is consumed by out site clients. (**I now have 2 projects under my solution**)

Recently there are some enhancements for the class Library. I would like to implement Versioning on this library (not quite sure how to do it.).

Let's say my current "**Class Library v1**" should be still active as some of our clients who consume the "**Web Service**" still need "**Class Library v1**" implementation. But for few new clients my "**Web Service**" should implement "**Class Library v2**" logic.

I started duplicating my "**Class Library v1**" and create new project in my solution "**Class Library v2**" and handled it in my "**Web Service**" project based on the request origin. (**I now have 3 projects under my solution**)

For some reason I feel this is very amateur way of implementation. Can any one guide me to do right way of versioning libraries and invoke those appropriately.

Comment: Look into the properties of the project - you can set the assembly version number and version name there.

Comment: Check out ClickOnce http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.80).ASPX

Comment: I think he's asking more about how to implement versioning via the web service rather than DLL version numbering. The naive solution would be to just duplicate V1, rename it V2, and have two implementations that are almost identical.  Of course, over time this becomes a maintenance nightmare.  I suppose your approach would vary based on how your web service is actually implemented.  If it's SOAP-based, then you'll probably need to go down the route of different endpoints. If it's REST-based, you could do version decisions based on a client-specified HTTP header, for example.

Comment: @martin_costello it's rest based.

Comment: @HaBo I'm going to edit your question's title with something that would be better identified by others as the actual issue

Comment: @HaBo I believe that now the title is more self-explanatory, are you agree with me?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I do, but it is not specific to web services though. Nay ways I got my answer I am good.

Comment: @HaBo Well, your original question had something to do with Web service versioning, but you're right, this Q&A might be useful in a lot of scenarios, but this is up to reader's decision :D You're welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this is implemented using version control *branches*.

- There's a *main* branch which represents the most up-to-date code (and the branch that evolves independently of product versions or milestones).
- When you want to release a new version or revision, first step is tagging the source control version item with a version tag. For example: "My product 2.2".
- Also, if the whole product version or revision will be maintained in parallel with newer ones, you need to create a *version/revision* branch, so specific patches, fixes or features will be implemented there without affecting newer or older versions. If you want to share a feature in different branches, you'll need to *merge* the whole changset. The main problem with this is that sometimes the code base in older versions won't support a merge, but you'll need to develop the fix again for the specific version...
- Sub, sub-sub, sub-sub-sub branches might happen. For example, you might have 2.x branch, and a sub branch for 2.1.x, 2.2.x... It all depends on how you handle versioning and product releases.
- Each branch is a different Visual Studio solution. You shouldn't mix satellite libraries in the same solution. Manage them alone in their own solution with specific code file versions.

At the end of the day, you've all code branches in separate source control repositories, and you develop each version separately, then you merge changes (or implement the change for a specific version).

Now you need to choose a source control provider. You've many options:

- GIT ([I've found this guide, it might be a good start for you on GIT](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/))
- Mercurial.
- Subversion (*too old*).
- Others...

The source control provider comparison goes outside the scope of this Q&A and it's very opinion-oriented, and this won't fit StackOverflow conventions, but it's up to you to review some of them or even find out others!

### About the web service

In terms of serving your Web service exposing many versions to your consumers, you might need to think about an URI scheme where base URI contains Web service version:

- `/api/v1/resourceA`
- `/api/v2/resourceA`
- `/api/v2.2/resourceA`
- ...

### Update based on some OP's comment

> [...] I am more interested to know last part of your answer where you gave
>   sample URLs for web service API. let's say I maintain different end
>   points such as v1, v2 and v2 for all clients, now my confutions is
>   when the request is from v1 URL and V2 url should I invoke my single
>   class library or two different class libraries.

As I pointed out in this answer above, you'll need to maintain each version of your solution separately, and you'll need to deploy each version as a different IIS application.

Maybe you'll need to learn *[WebDeploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy)* a bit to deploy your solutions with less effort.

If you go with the *one solution and v1,v2,v3 class libraries* approach, you'll experience a lot of issues in the future, because you'll modify some code that will work in the latest version, that mightn't work in a previous one.

Just imagine that your v1 API works with .NET 3.5, v2 works with .NET 4.x and v3 .NET vNext (5?). You won't be able to build/compile your Web service solution into a single application which can work with more than a .NET CLR in the same IIS app (*this is one of possible issues, we can continue with the next ones ;P!)

Comment: The question seems more about how to serve one version through the webservice to some clients and a newer version to other clients...

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid I believe it's a mix of what you said and my answer. OP asked *For some reason I feel this is very amateur way of implementation. Can any one guide me to do right way of versioning libraries and invoke those appropriately?*, and I feel that my answer should be a good start!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer thank you. Your answer helps to understand the Source Control versioning. I am more interested to know last part of your answer where you gave sample URLs for web service API. let's say I maintain different end points such as v1, v2 and v2 for all clients, now my confutions is when the request is from v1 URL and V2 url should I invoke my single class library or two different class libraries.

Comment: But the key phrase there is "*and invoke those appropriately*" - while VCS will indeed help in the build and maintenance of the codebase, eventually they will need to host multiple instances of the library and service for the different clients.

Comment: @HaBo It's already answered in my answer! This is why I used more time in explaining you how to branch projects rather than the other part. The answer is you should maintain different solutions, and you can deploy each of them in different IIS Web sites, or Web site applications.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid Yeah, absolutely, this is why I answered that the prefered approach will be maintaining a solution per version.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Yea I read it, just making sure I understood it correctly. Thank you.

Comment: @HaBo Check my update, even when you marked it as the right answer ;P It might be an useful advise!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Thank you. So any versioning should be done on Source control via branching and deploy it as a seperate sites on IIS. So I need to focus on finding out how to create a build branch of whole solution and deploy those builds

Comment: @HaBo You know there's a great tool for that: TFS 2013 which has GIT support and TFS Build! Also, now Microsoft Azure has Visual Studio Online, a TFS cloud version and I believe it's very cheap. Disclamer: I'm not affilate with Microsoft or Azure. It's just a suggestion :D